# keep current src attr so I can retrieve image

Tags: jquery

Code is like this :

```
$(' html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a ').hover(
function() {
        $(' html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a > img ').attr("src", "http:/site/test1.png");
},
 function() {
        $('html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a > img ').attr("src", "currentSrc");
});
```

I just need to keep the src value of the image before the change so on mouseleave I can retrieve the image and display it.

Comment: (a) You probably can omit some tags/classes from your selector (like `html` and `body`) because they don't add any specificity to the selector. (b) Inside the event handler, you can use `this` to refer to the element (i.e. `$(this)`), you don't have to use the selector anymore. (c) Be happy about simper code :)

Comment: First of all, your selector is overkill. `$('div.post_home:first-child a')` should do the trick. A good way to store things is with the html5 data attribute: `$(this).data('src')`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15192185/1250044

Comment: @FelixKling thnx I wasn't sure about it so I used the whole Path so there would be no mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your `src` attrivute at the start of your event before changing it. And use it when you want to go to back.

```
var currentSrc;
$('.post_home:first-child a ').hover(function() {

    currentSrc = $('.post_home:first-child a > img').attr("src");
    $('.post_home:first-child a > img ').attr("src", "http:/site/test1.png");

}, function() {

        $('.post_home:first-child a > img').attr("src", currentSrc);

});
```

**Note:** I edited your selectors because what you have is more than necessary.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my code. I was doing the same but my mistake was using quotes at the variable currentSrc inside the attr method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` attributes to store your src to retrieve later:

```
var thisImg;
$('.post_home:first-child a').hover(function () {
    thisImg = $('img', this)[0];
    $(this).data('img-src', thisImg.src);
    thisImg.src = "http:/site/test1.png";
}, function () {
    thisImg.src = $(this).data('img-src');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2uc3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the original src in a variable to use it later. Something like this:

```
var originalSrc = $(' html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a > img ').attr('src');
$(' html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a ').hover(
function() {
        $(' html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a > img ').attr("src", "http:/site/test1.png");
},
 function() {
        $('html body div.wrapper div.middle div.post_home:first-child a > img ').attr("src", originalSrc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML5 [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), so you can store the original url in the "src" prop and in a `data-src="my other image"` the image you want to change.

```
<img src="my original image" data-src="my other src" />
```